# How can I get return value from int method inside main class

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm new in C#. I want to show my return values from my `MyApp` method.

```
    public int MyApp(string strFirst, string strSecond)
    {
        if (strFirst.Equals(strSecond))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < strFirst.Length; i++)
        {
            string temp = strFirst.Substring(0, strFirst.Length - 1);
            temp = strFirst[strFirst.Length - 1] + temp;
            strFirst = temp;
            if (strFirst.Equals(strSecond))
            {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Use `Console.WriteLine` or `Console.Write`.

Comment: Why did you choose to not use Console.WriteLine?  Is there a specific reason?

Comment: There is no spesific reason. I want to just show my return values to user. Everything can be.

Comment: @SerhatGüneş, the issue you are describing is probably unrelated to `Console.WriteLine()` - in fact it reflects an error in the function you're returning from.

Comment: using multiple returns inside 1 function is not a good idea, instead you could make an int variable and make it assume different values inside your function based on the conditions and then you just have to return the single int variable. Ps:this is what your need Console.WriteLine(<your variable>)

Answer (score 3):

If you do not call `Console.WriteLine()`, nothing will be printed to the console.
So do:

```
Console.WriteLine(calc.MyApp("try", "yrt"));
```

And we usually name methods with descriptive verbs - so your `MyApp` should become `Calculate`.
Whereas classes should be named with nouns - so your `Calculate` should become `MyApp`.
That way, your code is more expressive:

```
var app = new MyApp();
Console.WriteLine(app.Calculate("try", "yrt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Calculate calc = new Calculate();

        int result = calc.MyApp("try", "yrt");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on this line:

```
calc.MyApp("try", "yrt");
```

You are calling your `MyApp` method, but you are not storing or using the result.

Storing the result in a variable is useful if you intend to use the result for other things:

```
//Store the result
var result = calc.MyApp("try", "yrt");
//Display the result
Console.Writeline(result);
```

You can also just pass the expression (the call to method `MyApp`) as an argument to the `Writeline` method:

```
Console.Writeline(calc.MyApp("try", "yrt"));
```

The runtime will execute the call to your method and use the result as the argument of the call to method `Writeline`.

Either way works. I personally would recommend using a variable if you are just getting started. Inline calls save space and can be more performant but they also make debugging harder.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Console.WriteLine()` and it always returns -1 where it shouldn't your problem lies with the code in the MyApp() Method.

The real problem is that you are rotating your first string and not turning it around. 
So, if your first string is "hello" and your second string is "olleh" - for each iteration you will get the following for your first string:

1. ohell
2. lohel
3. llohe
4. elloh
5. hello

You will never get "olleh"